# node version issue on ionic serve

Tags: ionic-framework, version

I have to use node v8 in an ionic project I have installed angular 8 and node v8 but when I'm doing ionic serve it's throwing 'ERR: Your Node.js version is v8.0.0. Node.js 8 reached end-of-life on 2019-12-31 and is no longer supported. Please update to the latest Node LTS version.'

Comment: Update your Node, Why are you using Older version?

Comment: Thanks! @NajamUsSaqib I have updated but still facing an error : npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! node-sass@4.5.0 postinstall: `node scripts/build.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the node-sass@4.5.0 postinstall script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

Comment: Are you using MAC or Ubuntu?? Also try `npm rebuild node-sass`  command and see if it works.